# How to find the joint PDF and conditional expectation of two dependent variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a uniform random variable over $[0,1]$ and $\mathbf{y}$ the random variable defined by $\mathbf{y}=e^{\mathbf{x}}$. I'd like to show that
$$
E(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}=x)=e^x
$$
By definition,
$$
\begin{align}
E(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}=x)
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y f_{\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}}(x,y) dy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y \frac{f_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(x,y)}{f_{\mathbf{x}}(x)} dy
\end{align}
$$
Thus, I first tried to find the joint p.d.f.,
$$f_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(x,y)$$
but it became $0$ and I cannot obtain the conditional expectation.

**My attempt**

First, I computed the c.d.f. of $\mathbf{y}$ by change of variable:
$$
\begin{align}
F_{\mathbf{y}}(y) &= P(\mathbf{y}\leq y) \\
&=P(e^\mathbf{x}\leq y)\\
&=P(\mathbf{x}\leq \log(y))
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, when $0\leq \log(y)\leq 1$, or $1\leq y \leq e$, the c.d.f. is
$$
\begin{align}
F_{\mathbf{y}}(y) &=\int_{0}^{\log(y)}f_{\mathbf{x}}(x)dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\log(y)}1dx \\
&= \log(y) \\
\therefore f_{\mathbf{y}}(y) &= \frac{d}{dy}F_{\mathbf{y}}(y) = \frac{1}{y}\\
\therefore f_{\mathbf{y}}(y) &=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{y} & 1\leq y \leq e\\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, we consider the joint c.d.f. of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$:
$$
\begin{align}
F_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(x,y) &= P(\mathbf{x}\leq x, \mathbf{y}\leq y)\\
&= P(\mathbf{x}\leq x, e^\mathbf{x}\leq y)\\
&= P(\mathbf{x}\leq x, \mathbf{x}\leq \log(y))\\
&= 
\begin{cases}
P(\mathbf{x}\leq x) & \text{if }\  x\leq \log(y) \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\\
\\
P(\mathbf{x}\leq x\leq \log(y)) &= \int_{0}^{\log{x}}f_{\mathbf{x}}(x)dx\\
&= \log(x)
\\
\\
\therefore \ F_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(x,y) &=
\begin{cases}
 \log(x) & \text{if }\  x\leq \log(y) \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Finally, we compute the joint p.d.f. by a partial derivative of the joint c.d.f.:
$$
\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(x,y) 
&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}F_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(x,y)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$
Strangely, my result becomes $0$. I'm sure I'm messing up something in my calculation. I appreciate any suggestions or corrections!

Comment: Unfortunately a joint PDF does not exist. The random vector $(X,Y)$ only takes values on the curve $\{(x,y) : y=e^x\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so if a joint PDF were to exist it would have to be zero almost everywhere (which I think your computation shows).

Comment: Thank you, @angryavian. If that's the case, is there any way to compute the conditional expectation without using the joint PDF? I updated my question to make my point clearer.

Comment: Given the event $X=x$, you actually have $Y=e^x$. So you have the stronger statement $P(Y=e^x \mid X=x) = 1$ which implies $E[Y \mid X=x] = e^x$.

Comment: Aha, that totally makes sense!!!! I didn't notice at all until you point it out! I even didn't have to compute any PDFs... Thank you!